# How to use TabbedPage in Xamarin WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to rebuild my old WinForms application using Xamarin Forms for more portability.

The application uses a `TabControl`, and [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/desktop/controls/) say that the closest Xamarin Forms element is the `TabbedPage`.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
            x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Tools"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="1" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Help"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="2" />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <ContentPage Title="Main">
            <Label Text="Coming soon!"/>
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Today">
            <Label Text="Coming soon!"/>
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="This week">
            <Label Text="Coming soon!"/>
        </ContentPage>

    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

It works well on my UWP build:

[image]

However, on my WPF build, it does not show the toolbar, making it impossible to switch tabs:
[image]

So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

#### Update #1: I've tried to build the GTK target, it works correctly:

[image]
This screenshot is taken on Ubuntu. GTK# on Windows works the same way, but the drawing of the controls are too buggy.

Comment: I think the comparison table was telling you that you have to use TabControl for WPF and WinForm.

Comment: @Shaw Yes. If I program on WinForms, I have to use TabControl. However, I am using Xamarin Forms to output a WPF-like app so I must use TabbedPage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing up with the element picker in the toolbar, I've finally found an answer:

There ARE buttons to switch between tabs in WPF. However, they are just invisible:[image]

Setting the `BarTextColor` property in `TabbedPage` fixes the problem:
[image]

So the resulting code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimetableApp"
            x:Class="TimetableApp.MainPage" 
            BarTextColor="Black">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Tools"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="1" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Help"
                     Order="Primary"
                     Priority="2" />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <ContentPage Title="Main">
            <Label Text="Coming soon!"/>
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Today">
            <Label Text="Coming soon!"/>
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="This week">
            <Label Text="Coming soon!"/>
        </ContentPage>

    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```